# How to show array of images or any array of objects in a grid in xcode macos

Tags: arrays, swift, macos, gridview, xcode10

Hiii. the question is simple.

As a beginner in Xcode for MacOS app, I have an array of imageViews with this code:

```
var imageViews = [NSImageView]()
```

and it works fine when I want to load one of them in an imageView like this:

```
imageView1.image = imageViews[2].image
```

but I want to have a grid of all the images. After using for loop, i don't know how to load them in a gridView or collectionView or tableView or similar options.
because i cant find any simple option like:

```
gridview1.items.add(imageViews[i].image)
```

or

```
collectionView1.items.add(imageViews[i].image)
```

I actually mean how to show any array of objects in a grid.
For example a book class that has a cover image and a label for its title and we have about 200 or more of them and by clicking on each of them, the folder of the item will be opened. Hope I didn't say it in a confusing way.

Answer (score 0):

I think using NSCollectionView will be your best option.  Here is the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview) from apple:

And here is a tutorial from [raywenderlichs](https://www.raywenderlich.com/783-nscollectionview-tutorial) site on how to display images in a collection view.
Another tutorial for creating the collection view [programmatically](https://dev.to/onmyway133/making-nscollectionview-programatically-in-swift-2i85).

With the collection view you're able to specify the layout and easily configure the entire setup.

Once you have your datasource of images, the collectionView displays them one at a time from inside of collectionView(_:itemForRepresentedObjectAt:)

Comment: Thanks again for reply. I tried to understand these tutorials, but none of them was for me and they were a bit hard. It might seem silly, but I have a c# windows form programming background and want something as easy as in c#.
You might know that there we can have a panel (like a view here) and use a simple code like      panel1.controls.add(pictureBox1)     and then we can control it's x & y or count manually. It might be a little time consuming but so easy to understand. 
I'd like to do the same here if its possible.